# Orthogonal Trajectory of $y^2 = kx^3$

Tags: calculus

### Find the orthogonal trajectories of the family of curves.

### $$\mathtt{y^2 = kx^3}$$

Take the derivative, $\frac{d}{dx}$

$$2y = k3x^2\frac{dy}{dx}$$

$$\frac{2y}{k3x^2}=\frac{dy}{dx}$$

---

Bring in $\mathtt{k}$

$$\frac{2y}{\frac{y^2}{x^3}3x^2}=\frac{dy}{dx}$$

---

Simplify

$$\frac{2yx^3}{k3x^2y^2}=\frac{2x}{3y}=\frac{dy}{dx}$$

---

Find perpendicular slope by taking negative reciprocal

$$-\frac{3y}{2x}=\frac{dy}{dx}$$

---

Integrate

$$\int-\frac{1}{2x}dx = \int\frac{1}{3y}dy$$
$$-\frac{x^2}{4}+C = \frac{y^2}{6}$$

---

Simplify

$$6(-\frac{x^2}{4}+C) = y^2$$
$$\mathtt{y=\sqrt{6(C -\frac{x^2}{4})}}$$
Can someone check my work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{y^2}{x^3}=k~~~(1)$$ D.w.r.t. $x$ yto get the ODE for the curve as
$$2xy'=3y\implies 2xy'=3y ~~~~(2)$$ To get the orthogonal family of curves change $y'$ to $-\frac{1}{y'}.$ Then, we get $$2x=-3yy' ~~~(2)$$ Then
$$2xdx=-3ydy \implies \int 2x dx= \int -3y dy+C \implies 2x^2+3y^2=D,~ D=2C.$$
These are family of ellipses.

**Note for OP**: In the ODE of the curve just change $y'$ to $\frac{-1}{y'}$ for the othogonal curve. This works ingeneral for the ODE $y'~^2+y'=x$
the orthogoal family of curbes will satisfy $\frac{1}{y'~^2}+\frac{-1}{y'}=x$.
The ''negative reciprocal'' of the curve is ambiguous and it should be avoided.
See the figure for both family of curves:

[image]

Comment: ah, I see where I went wrong now. Thank you!